# Logical constraints in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, opl

I am a beginner at using CPLEX and I have come across a problem with creating logical constraints (if ... then ...). I use IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio version 12.7. According to the [the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_types_logical.html), it should be able to handle logical constraints by using "=>" (e.g., "if x>0 then y>=2" should become `x>0 => y>=2`).

The problem consists of assigning a start and end of a shift to employees (or a 0 if they are not working today). I am trying to create a variable that functions like an indicator for whether they are working in order to use it for assigning costs later.

I have boiled my code down to the following:

```
using CP;

tuple TimeSlot { 
    key int day;
    key int slotNo;
}
{TimeSlot} TimeSlots = ...;
{int} mondays = {t.slotNo|t in TimeSlots:t.day==1};
int monMax = max(t in mondays) t;
range monRange = 0..monMax;

range allEmployees = 1..10;

dvar int monStart[allEmployees] in monRange;    //Start of monday shift
dvar int monEnd[allEmployees] in monRange;      //End of monday shift
dvar int monAtWork[allEmployees] in 0..1;       //Binary

//minimize ...

subject to{
    forall(t in allEmployees)
        {monStart[t] > 0 && monEnd[t]>0} => monAtWork[t] = 1; //Get error here
}
```

The error I get is `syntax error, unexpected =`. I have tried both splitting and flipping the constraint (e.g., `monStart[t] == 0 => monAtWork[t] = 0;`) to no avail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the provided OPL examples (e.g. BasketballScheduling\acc.mod) I think that the 'then' part defining the constraint should have '==' rather than '='. It is not an assignment, but declaring that the two must be equal.

Comment: I tried changing it, and it gave a different error: `Operator not available for {boolean} => boolean`. But as far as I can see, that is also what they're using in the example you mentioned. Strange.

Comment: Can't edit the comment. Removing the `{}` around the left hand side fixed the last bit of the problem. It seems that the logical constraints are only `boolean => boolean`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using CP;

tuple TimeSlot { 
    key int day;
    key int slotNo;
}
{TimeSlot} TimeSlots = {<1,1>,<2,2>};;
{int} mondays = {t.slotNo|t in TimeSlots:t.day==1};
int monMax = max(t in mondays) t;
range monRange = 0..monMax;

range allEmployees = 1..10;

dvar int monStart[allEmployees] in monRange;    //Start of monday shift
dvar int monEnd[allEmployees] in monRange;      //End of monday shift
dvar int monAtWork[allEmployees] in 0..1;       //Binary

//minimize ...

subject to{
    forall(t in allEmployees)
        (monStart[t] > 0 && monEnd[t]>0) => monAtWork[t] == 1; //Get error here
}
```

works fine